# on_reaction_add only being called when bot initially adds reaction to message

Tags: python, discord.py

I have some code

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print("hello")
    if(user.id == bot.user.id):
        return
    if(not reaction.message.guild):
        await reaction.message.delete()

@bot.command(name="dm", brief="Anonymously dms user")
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, message=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if(message is None):
        await ctx.send("Enter a message to send to this user!")
        return
    msg = await user.send("**An anonymous user sent you this:** "+message)
    await msg.add_reaction("\U0001F5D1")
```

on_reaction_add is only being called when my bot initially adds a reaction to it's own message. When I try to add a reaction to the message, hello is not printed into the terminal and there's no error at all either.

Edit: Fixed issue by using on_raw_reaction_add instead of on_reaction_add.

Comment: Is the message cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_reaction_add()` requires the message to be in the internal message cache. Try using this instead:

```py
on_raw_reaction_add(payload)
```

See more information [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=event#discord.on_raw_reaction_add).

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it worked perfectly!